# Why can I create user defined structured bindings for glm::vec in MSVC and icc, but not Clang and GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, c++17, glm-math

I've been using code similar to the following in MSVC projects for the last year or so, and ran into an issue trying to use it with g++.

```
#include <utility>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

namespace std {
  template< std::size_t I, auto N, class T, auto Q>
  constexpr auto& get(glm::vec<N, T, Q>& v) noexcept { return v[I]; }

  template< std::size_t I, auto N, class T, auto Q>
  constexpr const auto& get(const glm::vec<N, T, Q>& v) noexcept { return v[I]; }

  template< std::size_t I, auto N, class T, auto Q>
  constexpr auto&& get(glm::vec<N, T, Q>&& v) noexcept { return std::move(v[I]); }

  template< std::size_t I, auto N, class T, auto Q>
  constexpr const auto&& get(const glm::vec<N, T, Q>&& v) noexcept { return std::move(v[I]); }

  template <auto N, class T, auto Q>
  struct tuple_size<glm::vec<N, T, Q>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> { };

  template <std::size_t I, auto N, class T, auto Q>
  struct tuple_element<I, glm::vec<N, T, Q>> {
    using type = decltype(get<I>(declval<glm::vec<N,T,Q>>()));
  };
}// end std


auto f(){
  auto [x,y,z] = glm::vec3(1);
  return x + y + z;
}
```

GCC gives the error `error: 'get' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::get'?`
Clang gives the error `error: use of undeclared identifier 'get'`
icc and MSVC both compile properly.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with GLM's implementation, because I've never had issues with custom structured bindings with GCC in the past.

I was wondering if anyone knows what is going on here. Are icc and MSVC behaving incorrectly by accepting the code, or are Clang and GCC behaving incorrectly by rejecting the code?

Here's an example of the four different compilers handling this on Compiler Explorer:
https://godbolt.org/z/6PCWyn

Comment: Sorry for raising the dead but... would you mind updating your code with your final version? I tried using it (after adjusting as suggesting below) but then if I try to bind to `const` variables (e.g. `const auto [x,y,z] = ...`, clang complains that "rvalue reference to type 'const float' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'const float'"

Comment: I fixed the issue I mentioned in my previous comment with `using type = T;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe GCC & Clang are correct.

Here's what [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) says about structured bindings:

> The expression `std::tuple_size<E>::value` must be a well-formed integer constant expression, ...
>
> For each identifier, a variable whose type is "reference to `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`" is introduced ... The initializer for the i-th variable is
>
> - `e.get<i>()`, if lookup for the identifier `get` in the scope of `E` by class member access lookup finds at least one declaration that is a function template whose first template parameter is a non-type parameter
> - Otherwise, `get<i>(e)`, **where `get` is looked up by argument-dependent lookup only, ignoring non-ADL lookup**.

(emphasis mine)

You have to move your `get()` overloads to the `namespace glm`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I was wondering why something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/-kpHGt) would work but my first example wouldn't. I think when I originally wrote the code, I moved the `get()` overloads to `std` because it didn't work otherwise. But I never really tried to figure out what was going on.